# What building in the final scene of Assassins Creed? (spoiler)

Tags: realism, assassins-creed

The final scene crawls across the skyline of London to a building fronting the Thames. I recognized the Millennium Bridge and the London Eye, so I'm sure the scene was realistic.

The remaining assassins are grouped on a building with a clock. What is that building?

Secondarily: the clock reads 4:44, and it's dark. That means it's December/January and thus the Templar crowd spilling out of their HQ are dressed wrong. Or possibly the clock is broken.  But anyway, is there something significant about 4:44 in the Assassin's Creed mythology?  Or is it a tribute to some other film?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ely_Cathedral ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The remaining assassins are grouped on a building with a clock.

[image]

> What is that building?

It's [**Shell Mex House**](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.5111157,-0.1212984,227a,20y,180h,45t/data=!3m1!1e3) [Google Map/Earth Link]

[image]

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_Mex_House)

> Shell Mex House is a grade II listed building[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcUAf.png) situated at number 80, Strand, London, UK. The current building was built in 1930–31 on the site of the Hotel Cecil and stands behind the original facade of the Hotel and between the Adelphi and the Savoy Hotel. Broadly Art Deco in style, it was designed by Ernest Joseph of the architectural firm of Messrs Joseph.

[image]

<sup>(By Arild Vågen - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=31459889)</sup>

---

> Secondarily: the clock reads 4:44, and it's dark. That means it's December/January and thus the Templar crowd spilling out of their HQ are dressed wrong.

I assumed it was 4:44 in the morning so it would be dark. The event *starts* in the evening so it would seem logical that the end is at night/early morning. I confess though that the interior lighting is a little *confused*.

If you examine the final scene you reference, there are only a few lights on. If it was 4:44 in the afternoon and dark I can assure you there would be **many** more office lights on.

I'm not sure what you mean by dressed "wrong"...they all seem to be wearing overcoats or at least clothing suitable for a UK night.

---

As for 4:44 I can't find any specific *special* reference to that number being relevant in any particular way to the *Assassin's Creed* milieu/franchise but I'm not well versed in it.